# How to give dynamic size to the StoryView Class with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to show story like whatsapp and i found a plugin [story_view](https://pub.dev/packages/story_view#-readme-tab-)
but Unable to understand that How to give dynamic size to `StoryView` class.

I tried give size with `ListView.Builder()` but nothing useful.

**CODE:**

```
class ViewStatus extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ViewStatusState createState() => _ViewStatusState();
}

class _ViewStatusState extends State<ViewStatus> {
 final storyController = StoryController();
List<StoryItem> stories = new List();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setState(() {
            stories.add(
            StoryItem.pageImage(
              CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f6/eb/53/f6eb535411056b553dfdec1665387c0c.jpg"),
            caption: "Simply beautiful",
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    storyController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 4,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
         return StoryView(
            [
              stories[index]

            ],
            onStoryShow: (s) {
              print("Showing a story");
            },
            onComplete: () {
              print("Completed a cycle");
            },
            //You can place your progress position top or bottom
            progressPosition: ProgressPosition.top,
            repeat: true,
            controller: storyController,
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what you mean by dynamic size? what output you currently got?

Comment: means Sir, numbers of stories. BTW I got Solved. before I was getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

It got solved.
Actually I was Doing Worng means No need of ListView Builder.
so removed it,
now Working fine as Was Expecting.

```
return StoryView(
    stories
    onStoryShow: (s) {
        print("Showing a story");
     },
     onComplete: () {
        print("Completed a cycle");
         Navigator.pop(context);
      },
       //You can place your progress position top or bottom
      progressPosition: ProgressPosition.top,
      repeat: true,
      controller: storyController,
    );
```

Now I can give Dynamic Size to the loop.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 4,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,  
          child: StoryView(
            [stories[index]],
            onStoryShow: (s) {
              print("Showing a story");
            },
            onComplete: () {
              print("Completed a cycle");
            },
            //You can place your progress position top or bottom
            progressPosition: ProgressPosition.top,
            repeat: true,
            controller: storyController,
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Your answer is currently marked as low quality and faces deletion. Please make sure your answer contains an explanation aside from any code.